# Update dynamically-deep nested reducer

Tags: redux, react-redux

This question might have been asked a couple of times but I havent found my solution yet.

I have an app that saves an entry for each day, imagine a diary. The reducer that handles the entries is structured like so:

```
const initial_state = {}

{
  year: {
      month: {
          day: {
              entry: entryValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I want to update an existing entry in a given day I would do:

```
return {
      ...state,
      [payload.date.year]: {
        ...state[payload.date.year],
        [payload.date.month]: {
          ...state[payload.date.year][payload.date.month],
          [payload.date.day]: payload.data   
        }
      }
    };
```

Problem is that if its the first time the user is uploading an entry I get an error because

```
...state[payload.date.year][payload.date.month],
```

this would throw an error saying cannot read 1 (as in January for example) from undefined (since there is no year i.e. its just an empty object like in initial_state).

This makes me have to write logic that handles which action to take. I have to check if there is an entry or not first, then dispatch the correct action. So for example if its the first entry ever I would dispatch an action like this:

```
return {
      [payload.date.year]: { 
        [payload.date.month]: {
          [payload.date.day]: payload.data   
        }
      }
    };
```

My question is: Is there any way to write reducers in a way that you dont have to check for the existence of deep nested key-value pairs? Like for example checking if there is an entry in a given year?

More specific is there any way to make this not produce an error:

```
...state[payload.date.year][payload.date.month],
```

if `payload.date.year` is not existing in the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect case for using **JavaScript short-circuit**. I think this could be enough:

```
...(state[payload.date.year] || {})[payload.date.month]
```

Its a little *ugly* but I believe it is the shortest answer. The idea behind that line is to use an *empty object* as fallback in case such property doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was also thinking about this but struggling with the syntax.